# How to fetch slug object in /layouts/default.vue?

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js

In my `/projects/_slug.vue` I have the line:

```html
<Header :title="project.title" :subtitle="project.subtitle" />
```

by fetching the object in the same file with:

```js
async asyncData({ $content, params }) {
  const project = await $content("projects", params.slug).fetch();
  return { project };
}
```

Now my question: I'd like to move `Header` out of `/projects/_slug.vue` to `/layouts/default.vue`. Is it somehow possible to get `project.title` and `project.subtitle` in this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layouts don't have `asyncData`, but they support the [`fetch` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-fetch/). There, you could access the [Nuxt context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/internals-glossary/context) via `$nuxt.context`, which contains `$content()` and `$route` (for `params`):

```html
<template>
  <Header :title="project.title" :subtitle="project.subtitle" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      project: {}
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const { $content, route } = this.$nuxt.context;
    const { params } = route;
    this.project = await $content("hello", params.slug).fetch();
  },
}
</script>
```